# Draw region boundaries with Google Maps Api v3 as in Google Maps web page

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

If I search 'province of huelva, ES' in [Google Maps web page](http://maps.google.es/maps?q=province%20of%20huelva,%20ES), I get a marker and the province boundaries with a color layer, that even is filled when zoom out.

It is possible to use Google Maps API for getting that polygon (or layer, json object, ...) and even change its color just providing a query string like in the Google Maps web page?

For now I must use regions LatLng values for drawing a polygon, but would be great if I can get the polygon only providing a search string.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Getting that polygon is not possible at this time.